# how to cancel the function that unit test called times

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing

How to cancel the function that unit test called times? When I used unit test, it appear, buy how do I make it disappear? I can't find in Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable Code Coverage**

The code coverage annotation is drawn on the right and shows the count for how many times a particular part of the code was hit during the test.

Code coverage is a tool to measure the value of your tests.

1. Select Edit Scheme from the scheme editor menu.
2. Select the Test action.
3. Disable the Code Coverage checkbox to gather coverage data.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/07-code_coverage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH15-SW1)